# How can I find someone the most active tags one is questioning or answering?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-score

My tags I worked in my lifetime are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/239219/j%C3%A1nos?tab=tags).

But it does not express what tags / fields I am working nowadays the most. Is there any view which tells more about it?

Comment: It's not a "view", but a search. At the link in your question click on a tag, [iOS] for example, and restrict the date. Example: [`[ios]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A239219+%5Bios%5D+lastactive%3A2020-01-01..2021-12-12&searchOn=3) - everything for that tag from this past year, you can easily restrict it to a much shorter period. Remove the iOS tag to check all tags or use the **OR** operator to add additional tags. See the Search Help (advanced) that is offered when you click the link I mentioned to get additional ways to restrict the search. - There's no "view" in your profile.

Answer (score 6):

There is no such view, but you can simulate something like that with the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). The following query calculates your tag score for posts and votes limited to a certain time period. Remember that only (non-community-wiki) answers count towards the score. The query needs your user ID, which you can find in your profile. For example, [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1370223/tag-scores-limited-to-a-specific-period?fromDate=2019-01-01&tillDate=2999-12-31&UserId=239219) shows your activity since 2019:

[image]